# Evaluating $T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{5}) + \log n$: Master Theorem vs. Recursion Tree

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I'm wondering where (how? why?) my reasoning (by imagining the recursion tree) deviates from the application of the Master Theorem (Case 1) to this recurrence.

The Master Theorem gives $\Theta(n^{\log_{5}4})$, whereas reasoning from the recursion tree gives me $\Omega({\log n})$ and $O(\log^{2}n)$.

My rationale:

- Each level of the recursion tree totals $4^{L}\left(\log\frac{n}{5^{L}}\right)$ work, where $L$ is the level of the tree (zero-indexed). There are roughly $\lceil\log_{5}n\rceil$ levels in total, so roughly, this much work is being done:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{L=0}^{\lceil\log_{5}n\rceil} 4^{L} \log \frac{n}{5^{L}} &\leq (1 + \log_{5} n) (\log n)\\
                                                                                                &= O(\log^{2} n)
\end{align*}
$$

- A lower bound can be found by just taking the work done at the root of the tree: $\Omega(\log n)$.

---

I think I'm incorrectly assuming the work done at the root ($\log n$) serves as a per-level upper-bound. (I figured this was the case since at the leaf-level ($L = \log_{5} n$), the amount of work is $4^{\log_{5}n} (\log 1) = 0$?) I do notice that $4^{\log_{5}n} = n^{\log_{5}4}$, which is what the Master Theorem produces, but I can't square this with the tree.

Comment: how do you get the inequality? $4^L \log \frac{n}{5^L} = \log (\frac{n}{5^L})^{4^L}$. It seems strange to upperbound that with simple $\log n$

Comment: if you lower $+\log n$ term to a simple $+1$, does you argument still work?

Comment: @NooneAtAll3, yep, you're right -- I mistakenly upperbounded the level-by-level work with that (incorrectly thinking the root did at least much work as any subsequent level).